# In what cases it is good to use JQuery methods .submit() and .serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, serialization

I am a newbie in JQuery and I have 2 questions.

I know in code how to write and execute them .SUBMIT() and .Serialize() 
.But I am trying to figure out why these commands are used instead of regular .ajax commands
 like .post , .get.

a) **.submit()** - What is the reason of submitting a form with jquery command .submit() ?
      I mean usually I submit the values of the elements of the form by .ajax, .post or .get
      In which cases or what are the benefits by submiting the form with .submit

b) **.serialize()** -  I know how    the command .serialize works. But I haven΄t figure why to serialize
      the elements and the values of this form.
      Could you explain me practically also this?

Thank again for your time explaining !

Comment: Submitting a form is very different from performing an AJAX request; it's more like redirecting the browser to the next page, just as it they'd clicked the submit button. Serialising a form, on the other hand, is useful to capture the data the user has filled in *without* submitting the form.

Comment: Helpfull comments @@IMSop.So serialize or serializearray is a good way of capturing users choice before submiting for statistical reasons? Can be used also in search elements in order to capture users preferences?